# How to add a rel-canonical to product pages on Prestashop?

Tags: rel-canonical, prestashop

I am using Prestashop 1.6. Due a problem I have related to duplicated content I need to add a `rel`-`canonical` to some products.

I have been looking for but I didn´t find the way to implement `rel`-`canonical` per product page.

Could anoyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this within **preferences** and click the **SEO & URLS** tab, assuming that you have the module installed and enabled before hand. If you want more control over the SEO then you would be better off using a plug-in such as [zzSEOtk](https://github.com/ZiZuu-store/zzSEOtk/tree/dev), just one of many available. You could also adapt the template files to do this for you, but would require you to do your research on how to edit the files and how to use Prestashop hooks.

Comment: Hi Simon! Thanks for your answer. From SEO & URLs tab, you can not control the tag rel canonical per product page. The module you mentioned seems the ideal, however whan I have installed in my prestashop 1.6 I get an error...

Comment: You will then need to diagnosis the error or try a different module.